# how to solve an equation of the form $\binom n{r-a}=\binom n{r-b}$?

Tags: combinatorics

how to solve an equation of the form $\binom nr=\binom np$

More specifically I'm trying to solve
$$\binom {20}{r-1}=\binom {20}{r+3}$$ as part of a bigger problem
the issue is when expanded, this gives

$$\frac{1}{(r-1)(r-2)(r-3)(r-4){(21-r)!}}=\frac{1}{{(17-r})!}$$

however,I'm not sure of how I can simplify the other part($(21-r)! \text{ & } (17-r)!$)

I'd appreciate some advice

Comment: Think about the symmetry of Pascal’s triangle.

Answer (score 8):

$C(n,a)=C(n,b)$ if and only if $a=b$ or $a+b=n$

(You can prove this using induction on $n$)

Use this to find out the solution.